# JavaScript: match variable to element in array of arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I get the first two variables loaded from the backend, then I want to match the brand name I get back and return a two letter code. I put the associated brands in an array of arrays.

It doesn't seem `match()` is an option, cuz I can't put a variable in `regExp()`.

This didn't work:

```
if (brand.indexOf(brand_code[i])) {
    bc = brand_code[i][1];
}
```

This didn't work.

```
if (brand_code[i][0]===brand)
    bc = brand_code[i][1];
}
```

This is my latest attempt.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var phone_model='$request.getHeader("x-wurfl-model-name")',
        brand='$request.getHeader("x-wurfl-brand-name")',
        brand_code=[
            ['Alcatel','AL'],
            ['Huawei','HU'],
            ['LG','LG'],
            ['Motorola','MT'],
            ['Samsung','SA'],
            ['Unimax','UX'],
            ['ZTE','ZE']];
    for (var i = brand_code.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if ($.inArray(brand,brand_code[i])) {
            bc = brand_code[i][1];
        }
    }
    $('.faq .mobile_tutorial a').append(bc+phone_model);
});
```

This gives me an error of Cannot read property '3' of undefined
Where `phone_model='Z990g'` & `brand='ZTE'`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: indexOf returns a number of the index, not true/false. if not found, it returns `-1`. what is the content of `brand`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would structure your data differently in the variable `brand_code`, it would become a bit easier:

```
    brand_code={
        'Alcatel':'AL',
        'Huawei':'HU',
        'LG':'LG',
        'Motorola':'MT',
        'Samsung':'SA',
        'Unimax':'UX',
        'ZTE':'ZE'
    };
    bc = brand_code[brand];
}
```

This will not need to go through an array. Most JavaScript engines find the match in constant time if you use the object-based lookup above. In ES you can use a `Map` for the same purpose and with the same efficiency.

#### About your attempt

`$.inArray` returns 0 when `ZTE` matches the first element of an array, so the `if` condition would be `false` in that case. But worse, when `ZTE` is not found, the method returns -1, which makes the `if` condition true.

So, you would have had better results if you had put:

```
if ($.inArray(brand,brand_code[i])>-1) {
```

From the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/):

> The `$.inArray()` method is similar to JavaScript's native `.indexOf()` method in that it returns -1 when it doesn't find a match. If the first element within the array matches value, `$.inArray()` returns 0.

Comment: Thanks. Just be aware that performance-wise this beats `filter` and `reduce`, which have to iterate the array. But this is not relevant if the OP's data is small, like it seems to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array.filter` to find your match, then you can either check that the result's length > 0 and get `result[0][1]` from it, or use `Array.reduce` to return only the code:

```
// filter down to match and reduce the match to it's code value
brand_code.filter(function(pair) { 
    return pair[0] === brand 
}).reduce(function(out, match) { 
    return match[1]; 
}, '');
```

OR ES6:

```
brand_code.filter(pair => pair[0] === brand)
          .reduce((_, match) => match[1], '');
```

Comment: This is pretty neat, and I definitely wish ES6 were an option. Sadly, I have to support some devices still using Android 2.3.